# Copy report after kubernetes job is succeeded

Tags: automation, kubernetes

I have some services running on a namespace in kubernetes. I have created a job to run my api tests pointing to these services and when this job is finished(succeeded), I would like to be able to copy the json reports to my machine. I tried to use `kubectl cp` but this just works when the pod is still running.

Does anyone know how can I copy these reports after the job is completed ? I tried to create a deployment so I would be able to copy these reports, but then there is no `restartpolicy` for deployments and the tests were restarting everytime, which made me lost the reports before I was able to copy them. Also tried to just create a pod with the `restartpolicy: NEVER` but I had the same problem as the job.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: api-tests
  namespace: tests
spec:
    restartPolicy: Never
    containers:
    - name: api-tests
      image: api-tests:latest
      args: 
          - run
          - https://www.getpostman.com/collections/test23423423
          - -e
          - /etc/newman/envs/kubernetes.postman_environment.json 
          - -d
          - /etc/newman/data/tests.csv
          - --reporters
          - cli,html,json
          - --reporter-json-export
          - /etc/newman/target/api_tests.json
          - --reporter-html-export
          - /etc/newman/target/api_tests.html
          - --reporter-cli-no-failures
```

This is the `job.yaml` that I have at the moment.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: I have created a new issue to get this functionality without using a PersistentVolume: github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/111045 Please support me and give this ticket a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can push your reports to some system like git server, or you can place the reports to shared storage like nfs using [persistentvolume(PV)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes). Your jobs are going to run a specific node host then you can also review the [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) to share the reports with host server from pods.

I hope it helpful to you.